# Why are structured types are referenced by struct tag instead of typename?

Tags: linux-kernel

In Linux kernel, structured types are defined like that:

```
typedef struct _TAG_ { ... };
```

and then used in routines like that:

```
struct _TAG_ structured_entity;   
struct _TAG_ *pointer_to_structured_entity;
void function(struct _TAG_ *arg, ...);
```

Why not so:

```
typedef struct _TAG_ { ... } _typename_;
```

and then:

```
_typename_ structured_entity;   
_typename_ *pointer_to_structured_entity;
void function(_typename_ *arg, ...);
```

What is the technical necessity to do so?  Or is this simply tradition / style / magic?

Comment: There's no technical reason, typedef and the struct tag are equivalent. Using struct is more explicit and doesn't pollute the main namespace.

Comment: @Mat Are you sure about "doesn't pollute the main namespace"?

Comment: Yes. Structs tags live in a separate namespace (this is true for C only, C++ doesn't have this quirk and the typedef "trick" doesn't apply there). As soon as you typedef, you "pollute" the main namespace with struct names.

Comment: Therefore this is a technical reason :-) Thank you Mat.

Answer (score 2):

The [Linux kernel coding style](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/CodingStyle) - at kernel.org and in the Documentation directory that comes with the kernel - discourages using typedefs for structs:

```
Chapter 5: Typedefs

Please don't use things like "vps_t".

It's a _mistake_ to use typedef for structures and pointers. When you see a

    vps_t a;

in the source, what does it mean?

In contrast, if it says

    struct virtual_container *a;

you can actually tell what "a" is.
```

The document goes on to list cases where the author believes typedefs are useful - such as an opaque object that can only be accessed using accessor functions - concluding with:

```
In general, a pointer, or a struct that has elements that can reasonably
be directly accessed should _never_ be a typedef.
```